# Add 5 days to a Date in Java

Tags: java

i have a variable which gives me random dates in this format `"dd/MM/yyyy".I want my code to add 5 days in this date like this.

```
05/12/2022 ---> 10/12/2022
```

The code i found on internet is this

```
String stringDate="05/12/2022";
Date date1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(stringDate);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date1);
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 5);
Date dateWith5Days = cal.getTime();
System.out.println(dateWith5Days+" is the date after adding 5 days.");
```

Output

```
Sat Dec 10 00:00:00 IST 2022 is the date after adding 5 days.
```

Expected output

```
10/12/2022 is the date after adding 5 days.
```

Comment: Don't use Date, there are far better DateTypes to use nowadays. If you want that output, you'll need to apply a formatter.

Answer (score 3):

You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Define a custom format to match your input and output.

```
DateTimeFormatter f  = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) ;
```

Parse input using that format.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
```

Add five days. Notice how these classes use immutable objects. We instantiate a second `LocalDate` object rather than mutate the original.

```
LocalDate fiveDaysLater = ld.plusDays( 5 ) ;
```

Generate text in your desired format.

```
String output = fiveDaysLater.format( f ) ;
```